# Building custom authentication in an MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects - web forms and MVC. The user's session begins in the web forms project, e.g. they login via a page in that project

I am replacing the web forms with controllers in MVC. What I am trying to do is enforce authentication.

Currently in each action, I check for a session, like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var session = new BusinessLayer.User(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["appname"]);
    if (!session.IsAdminUser())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    // continue processing as we are an admin user
}
```

But I'd like to either inherit from a base class at the controller level, or I'd like to decorate each action with an attribute so authentication is enforced.

Further more, I will need access/scope to the returned value of BusinessLayer.User() in the actions

What is the best way to go about this? I prefer to use the decoration via attributes as there are cases where some methods do not require authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a filter, specifically a class that inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`.

You could do something like this:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = new BusinessLayer.User(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["appname"]);
        if (!session.IsAdminUser())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary { {"controller", "YourControllerName"}, {"action", "Index"} });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    // if you want, here are the rest of the overrides, but I only use OnActionExecuting

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then decorate your Action methods with `[CustomFilter]`.

(You'll have to supply the correct Controller name and possibly supply more values in the RouteValueDictionary depending on your route definition.)